# How to read a value from Realtime Databse using Cloud Functions?

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have a Cloud Functions, which triggers if a certain value in my Realtime Database changes. After that I need to read an other value from the Database.

I searched the web and found one solution. It worked: The function triggered as soon as the value at `/ID/temp_id` changed, but it took additional 5 seconds to read the value at `/ID/I`.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.getID = functions.database.ref("/ID/temp_id").onUpdate((change, context)=>{   //triggers the function when value "temp_id" changes
  const tempID = change.after.val();

  const i_snap = admin.database().ref("/ID/i").once("value", function(snapshot){      //read the value at "/ID/i" from the databse
    const i = snapshot.val();
  })

})
```

Is there any way to read the value at `/ID/I` faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you cannot simply speed up a simple database write like that.  Be aware that Cloud Functions have an [unavoidable cold start](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/tips) time for the first invocation of your function on a new server instance.

I would actually not expect your function to work at all because you're not returning a promise that resolves when all the asynchronous work is complete in your function.  You're obliged to do that so that your [function terminates normally](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions).

Answer (score 0):

You have to trigger a function through an HTTP request by using `functions.https`. This allows invoke a synchronous function.
Use `functions.https` to create a function that handles HTTP events. The event handler for an HTTP function listens for the `onRequest()` event.
Used as arguments for `onRequest()`, the `Request` object gives you access to the properties of the HTTP request sent by the client, and the `Response` object gives you a way to send a response back to the client.

```
exports.date = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  // ...
});
```

More details documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events

Take a look at the example below:

```
var functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

//Call function via HTTP requests. This allows invoke a synchronous function 
exports.showValue = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    const params = req.url.split("/");
    const tempId = params[2];
    return admin.database().ref('ID/' + tempId).once('value', (snapshot) => {
        var value = snapshot.val();
        res.send(`
            <!doctype html>
            <html>
                <head>
                    <title>${value.name}</title>
                </head>
                <body>
                    <h1>Title ${value. name}, id ${value.id}</h1>
                </body>
            </html>`
        );
     });
});
```

Comment: Can you point out what specifically is different about this code that makes it fix the problem OP is having?

Comment: Call function via HTTP requests. This allows invoke a synchronous function

Comment: @Matthias Did you try it?

Comment: @Umbro Apparently the OP wants its Cloud Function to "triggers if a certain value in [his] Realtime Database changes". Calling the function via an HTTP request will not, by default, fulfill this requirement.